# Bootstrap Modal, modal-backdrop not dismissing modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got my modal working fine.  As in I click on a link it opens the modal, and there is a button in there that when clicked it dismisses the modal.

However, if I click the modal-backdrop that is generated it doesn't dismiss, but it is supposed to.

Anyone know why this is, the site is only local so I can't show an example.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Hey, did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same problem, but can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the attribute `data-backdrop="static"` on your button or a similar call on your javascript (don't know which one you're using since you haven't posted any code), then clicking the backdrop will not dismiss the modal.  Remove that attribute or javascript option and it should be working.

Here's the Bootstrap docs for it: [Bootstrap 3 documentation, look under the section "Options".](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

If that doesn't work, please post some code and we can better help you.

Comment: I am not using that attribute to my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry which code do you need?

My Bootstrap is being pulled in via CDN.

I'll throw up a codepen of my html and sass.

Comment: Whatever code you are using to call/open the modal: if a button is pressed, and/or if javascript is used to open the modal, please post it.  And probably the code for the modal itself as well.

Comment: By removing your custom CSS, I can get the the modal to go away when clicking on the background.  I can't really debug your custom CSS effectively, however, because you posted your non-compiled SASS and I don't have your SASS variables or an environment to use SASS. Edit: if you are using your custom CSS to give your modal a body and such, why not use what bootstrap has built in?

Comment: Hmm, did you remove it all? What did you replace it with?

Anyway I have updated my codepen with compiled css.

http://codepen.io/NickToye/pen/HtdAj

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7M3tp/1/

Whoops, saved that before I was ready. Anyway, this is your code using only the CDN Bootstrap CSS and JS, and jQuery.  No CSS added. Seems to work, though I would add a couple of divs in the modal to give it a body and such (as found on the Bootstrap website referenced in the answer).  Edit: added the divs in the modal to show what Bootstrap does for you.

Comment: Hmm ok, so definitely something in that modal css then I have.  I have a wider issue with this though, because I need to only show the modal functionality in mobile and tablet, hence the more customised css.

I was starting another question but had to wait 90 minutes. :)

I can certainly debug this and see what's what though. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a URL to check. uniform.pixelsandcode.co.uk/arch-viz-image-library.html  I even did a click test on the backdrop and it doesn't even register a click.